# Ingress-Controller not working for services in multiple namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer, redis-sentinel

I am using Redis-Sentinel Configuration along with redisinsight. I have three redis-sentinel so I created 3 services(Services and ExternalName Service for this.). I have 2 namespaces: redis, ingress-nginx. I created ingress controller in ingress-nginx namespace. Below are my yaml files.

### ExternalName Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-s0-external
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: redis-s0.redis.svc.cluster.local

--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-s1-external
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: redis-s1.redis.svc.cluster.local

--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-s2-external
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: redis-s2.redis.svc.cluster.local
```

### Ingress-Controller

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: be-ingress
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: example.amazonaws.com  
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: redisinsight-external
                port:
                  number: 8001
          - path: /redis0
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: redis-s0-external
                port:
                  number: 26379
          - path: /redis1
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: redis-s1-external
                port:
                  number: 26379
          - path: /redis2
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: redis-s2-external
                port:
                  number: 26379
```

### Redisinsight

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redisinsight-service 
  namespace: redis
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: redisinsight
      port: 8001
      targetPort: 8001
  selector:
    app: redisinsight
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: redisinsight-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 3Gi  # Adjust the storage size as needed
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: gp2
  hostPath:
    path: /data/redisinsight-pv  # Replace with the actual path on the host

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: redisinsight-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: redisinsight
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  storageClassName: gp2
---
# RedisInsight deployment with name 'redisinsight'
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redisinsight #deployment name
  namespace: redis
  labels:
    app: redisinsight #deployment label
spec:
  replicas: 1 #a single replica pod
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redisinsight #which pods is the deployment managing, as defined by the pod template
  template: #pod template
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redisinsight #label for pod/s
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: db
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: redisinsight-pv-claim
      initContainers:
        - name: init
          image: busybox
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - '-c'
            - |
                            chown -R 1001 /db
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: db
              mountPath: /db
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
      containers:
        - name:  redisinsight #Container name (DNS_LABEL, unique)
          image: redislabs/redisinsight:latest #repo/image
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent #Always pull image
          volumeMounts:
          - name: db #Pod volumes to mount into the container's filesystem. Cannot be updated.
            mountPath: /db
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8001 #exposed container port and protocol
            protocol: TCP
```

When :
Ingress deployed in ingress-nginx namespace --> redisinsight working ;
Ingress in redis namespace --> redis services working [not exactly working but getting some response in raw format on webpage].